# How to put an icon on in the corner of a Material UI button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

How to put an icon in the corner of a Material UI button in react?

Now what I have is this, where the icon is right next to the title.
I wish to move the icon to the lower right corner of the button... Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks!

```
export default function CardButton() {
    return (
        <Button
            variant="contained"
            style={{
                height: 220,
                width: 275,
                margin: '1vh',
            }}
            color="secondary"
        >
            <Typography variant="button" style={{fontSize:'24px'}}>title</Typography>
            <AddIcon/>
        </Button>
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` to position the icon.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-a6phy9

Answer (score 0):

**Button Component**

```
<Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    fullWidth
    endIcon={<img src={your Icon source } />}
    className={classes.button}
  >
    Send
  </Button>
```

**Styles**

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  walletContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: "10px 20px",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.button,
    width: "500px",
    margin: "20px",
    outline: "none",
    border: "none",
    borderRadius: "6px",
  },
}));
```